# UWP: Retrieving installed fonts causes exception

Tags: uwp, win2d

In my UWP app, I have been retrieving the installed fonts using

```
try
   {
       var fonts = CanvasTextFormat.GetSystemFontFamilies();
       return (fonts.Length>0) ? fonts.OrderBy(f => f).ToList() : new List<string>();
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
       return new List<string>();
   }
```

Worked fine, until it did no longer. Now, I am getting the exception

```
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
   at Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Text.CanvasTextFormat.GetSystemFontFamilies()
   at FontHelper.<>c.<LoadInstalledFonts>b__11_0()}
```

I have moved this section into the UI Dispatcher, thinking that maybe there were restrictions in when and by whome `GetSystemFontFamilies()` can get called. That did not prevent the exception.

What is most galling: it worked before. No changes, now it just stopped working... Win2D is part of the project in version 1.25.0.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: I create a blank app with above code, it could return font list, could you share  more detail about your app's target version and your os version?

Comment: OS Win10 Home 18362.836   - Target 1809 (17763)

Comment: I have tested in same os version 18362. it also works, could you test in other computer ?

Comment: Currently not ready to ship to another computer... so will re-engage once that is done. For now, I simply used the list of guaranteed fonts in a Win10 installation as a static default return to the method if this call fails... crude but gets the job done at least a bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> UWP: Retrieving installed fonts causes exception

I can't reproduce your issue, But I have other way to get the system font info with [**SharpDx.Direct2D1**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX.Direct2D1) nuget package.

```
public void GetFontLibrary()
        {
            SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory factory = new SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory();

            var fontCollection = factory.GetSystemFontCollection(false);
            var familCount = fontCollection.FontFamilyCount;

            for (int i = 0; i < familCount; i++)
            {
                var fontFamily = fontCollection.GetFontFamily(i);
                var familyNames = fontFamily.FamilyNames;

                int index;

                if (!familyNames.FindLocaleName(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, out index))
                {
                    if (!familyNames.FindLocaleName("en-us", out index))
                    {
                        index = 0;
                    }
                }

                string name = familyNames.GetString(index);

                FontList.Add(name);
            }

        }
```